# AutoMapping Entity to Model

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper-6

I tried to map these but I am getting

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration
>   or unsupported mapping.'

```
public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public IList<MenuItemViewModel> Children { get; set; }
    public MenuItemViewModel Parent { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public IList<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
    public MenuItem Parent { get; set; }
    public bool onMenu { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }

    public IList<MenuItemPermittedRole> MenuItemPermittedRoles { get; set; }
}

Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<MenuItem, MenuItemViewModel>().ReverseMap();
});

MenuItemViewModel result = Mapper.Map<MenuItemViewModel>(menuItems); ERROR HERE
```

Comment: What does *no success* mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without knowing exactly which error are you receiving, but I can guess... If menuItems is an `IEnumerable<MenuItem>`, you should write

```
var result = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MenuItemViewModel>>(menuItems);
```